# Getting JSON data in Flask function

Tags: python, flask

I am just learning Flask. I am trying to get a JSON object through a jQuery call into flask. My html look like this,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Passenger</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form onsubmit="return false">
        <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <input class="submit" type="submit" placeholder="Go">
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    $("input.submit").click(function(e){
        $.post( "/save", {name: $("input.name").val(), time: "2pm"});
    });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The Flask app file looks like,

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask import request
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return redirect(url_for('static',filename='index.html'))

@app.route('/save', methods=['PUT','POST'])
def get_name():
  print request.json
  return request.json

if __name__=='__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Running this code returns None. I am expecting to get back the JSON object [{name: $("input.name").val(), time: "2pm"}]. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the jquery post is not using the data type of json.  You can see that by printing out the request content_type:

```
print request.content_type
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Change the Javascript to post json, and request.json should be populated with json as you expect.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({name: $("input.name").val(), time: "2pm"});
$.ajax("/save", {
    data: data,
    contentType : "application/json",
    type : "POST"
});
```

Notice that after changing the JS code, request.content_type will be application/json

Comment: Thanks! got it. Is it possible to convert the data I get back into json. How would the function change in that case?